# Wrong output using python strip() function

Tags: python, strip, parentheses

So I am having a weird issue here
When I am stripping a certain string which have parenthesis, its removing the first word after the parenthesis
Ex:

```
c = 'PurchaseOrderItem(d330d1adf0)'
print (c.strip("PurchaseOrderItem("+")"))
```

OUTPUT : `330d1adf0`

the above output should have the char 'd', but its removing it

Comment: See the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) it's clearly explained. *The chars argument is not a prefix or suffix; rather, all combinations of its values are stripped:*

Comment: To achieve your desired output, consider [`replace()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) function like `c.replace("PurchaseOrderItem(",'').replace(")",'')`